# Java CDI inject non zero args constructor

Tags: java, cdi

I'm playing with java standard CDI and there is one concept I cannot get my head around. In the example below the Application class "requires" the Person class which cannot be injected since it has non-zero args constructor. How should I handle this scenario with CDI?

```
@Default
class Person {
 private String name;
 Person(String name) {
  this.name=name;
 }
 String getName() {
  return this.name;
 }
}


class Application {
  @Inject
  public Application(Instance<Person> p)
}
```

Comment: Please explain your actual question. Also, how should CDI create objects with a non-zero argument constructor, where should it take the values the constructor should be called with?

Comment: Actually this is my question..how can I do the above. Is this not possible with CDI?

Comment: If you are using Instance, it seems you want to create more than one person, then how would CDI know each person's name? You should have a default constructor and a setter for the name. (If you really need to inject a domain entity such as a person, but that's an other question.)

Comment: Strangely enough, the documentation actually does show how: https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html

Comment: You can use `@Produces` method when you create your object by `new` and returning it. Despite creating it manually, `@Produces` will make it managed by CDI container.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to inject objects without a no-args constructor. One is to use a producer to create the object.

```
@Produces 
private Person producePerson() {
    return new Person(name);
}
```

The second is to annotate one of the constructors with @Inject and make sure all of the parameters are valid injection targets.

```
class Person {
    private String name;

    @Inject
    Person(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

and somewhere else:

```
@Produces 
private String producePersonName() {
    return name;
}
```

(Setting up multiple of these kinds of injections may require creating some qualifier annotations)

The third is to mess around with CDI container initialization with a custom extension, but that is overkill for such a relatively simple need.